# Can't check if the last 3 letters of an array are the same in java

Tags: java, arrays

I have to check if the last 3 numbers of a number with 3 or more digits are the same.
I have converted the number to a string called **nombre**.
My code is this:

```
for(int i=nombre.length()-1;(i<nombre.length() && i>=0);i--){
        if(nombre.charAt(i)==nombre.charAt(i-1)){
            res++;}
        }
        if(res==3){
            System.out.println("Les 3 derniers chiffres sont tous différents");
            
            }
        else if(res==2){
            System.out.println("Seuls deux des 3 derniers chiffres sont identiques");
            
            
            }
        else{
            System.out.println("Les 3 derniers chiffres sont tous différents");
            }
```

At the end I have to show if all the 3 digits are the same,or only the 2 digits ,or none of them.But I get an error that says: **String index out of range: -1** .I don't understand why because I already made a condition for *i* to be greater than 0.

Comment: When `i==0`, this `nombre.charAt(i-1)` isn't valid.  Where do you believe you "made a condition for i to be greater than 0"? (I see `i>=0`)

Comment: Okay I see,I've changed the condition for i to be i>0,but when I type for example the number 111,I get the message that says that only 2 out of 3 digits are the same.Do you know how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

## Code point

The `char` type is essentially broken since Java 2, and legacy since Java 5. As a 16-bit value, the `char` type is physically incapable of representing most of the over 140,000 characters defined in Unicode.

Use [code point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_point) integer numbers when working with individual characters.

```java
String input = String.valueOf( 789 );             // Convert an `int` primitive to text.
int[] codePoints = input.codePoints().toArray();  // Generate a stream of `int` primitives, each the code point for a character in our string. Collect those code points into an array.
```

## Stream

With the help of streams, we can do all the business logic in a one-liner.

Pull the last 3 code points, box them to make `Integer` objects from `int` primitives, and call [`Stream#distinct`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#distinct()) to eliminate duplicates. Get count of remaining digits.

```java
long size =
        Arrays
                .stream( codePoints )  // Make a stream of each code point in the array.
                .boxed()               // Convert from `int` primitive to `Integer` object.
                .toList()              // Make a `List` of those `Integer` objects.
                .subList( codePoints.length - 3 , codePoints.length )  // Focus on the last 3 digits’ code points only.
                .stream()              // Make a stream of those last 3 digits’ code points.
                .distinct()            // Eliminate duplicate code points.
                .count();              // Count remaining code points, and therefore a count of distinct digits in original number.
```

Use [`switch` expression](https://openjdk.org/jeps/361) to create a message for the result of our count of duplicate digits.

```java
String message =
        switch ( ( int ) size ) // Lossy cast needed, as oddly enough, in Java a switch cannot work on a `long` primitive.
                {
                    case 3 -> "No dups.";
                    case 2 -> "Two digits the same.";
                    case 1 -> "All three digits the same.";
                    default -> "ERROR - Unexpected switch case.";
                };
System.out.println( message );
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `nombre.charAt(i-1)` to `nombre.charAt(0)` to avoid that error and make that work.

```
for(int i=nombre.length()-1;(i<nombre.length() && i>=0);i--){
    if(nombre.charAt(i)==nombre.charAt(0)){
       res++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than get tangled up with indexes, you could use regex:

```
boolean last3Same = nombre.matches(".*(.)\\1\\1");
```

This also handles returning false if there are less than 3 characters in the string.